# Get an updated value from one component in another using react

Tags: reactjs

I have an application with a simple counter.
The counter works properly, but i can't get count value in `About` component, which can be accesed  adding in url `/about`. To acces `counter` value from store in  About.js component i made:

```js
const selector = useSelector(state => state);
  return <p>about page NR: {selector.counter}</p>...
```

*How to access the count value in About component, in real time, when i click on counter in main component?*

Now i just reproduced my issue in codesanbox, in my application i opned in my browser both pages. When i increment the value in main component, switching the tab to About component, i see only initial vaue `0`. So, what could be the issue? And how to solve it?

 **Expected scenario:** When i click on counter in main component to see the updated value in About component, having both pages opened.
 **DEMO**: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-hawking-wu1df?file=/src/App.js:174-222

Comment: The state value is store in the tab's memory and it is not shared.. so value in one tab would not refleect in another tab.

Comment: If you need.. you can either write to `localstorage` when updated and in another tab constantly fetch the localstorage and read it back..

Comment: or depend on a server to pass both states between the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The issue s that you use url to change the Route and when you do that the page is refreshed causing the data to be cleared.

If you use page navigation using `Link` from 'react-router, this code will work as expected.

In order to persist reducer changes on page refreshes you can store it in localStorage and retrieve it on load again.

Libraries such are [`redux-persist`](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#readme) help you handle such cases

With redux-persist, your code will look like

```
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <App />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

---

store.js

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import { reducer } from "./reducer";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);
let store = createStore(persistedReducer);
let persistor = persistStore(store);
export { store, persistor };
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-burnell-g64mf?file=/src/About.js)

Comment: i have a question, if i open both pages in my browser and after that i try to add a new value, and i change on the `/about` page, i don't get the updated value, why? PLease, let me know if is clear what i want to achieve.

Comment: Because there is no cross tab communication, you need to refresh it to trigger see the change. In order to inform the tab you would need to communicate using sockets

Comment: my code is just a try to simulate my real problem, in my real project i have next issue. I make a post request on page X, after that somebody who opened page Y from my application should receive the new item from post request, on page Y, but he receive the new item only if he refresh the page. What could be the issue? Or i get data from store  in Y component, but i can't see any activity when i post on X. Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: As I said browsers don't communicate cross tabs, if one tab makes certain actions on  page x and updates reducer, the second tab will be able to listen to those reducer changes directly. you need a page refresh to see that data[

Comment: it exists a possibility to force refresh the page Y whan i will post on page X. NOTE: The page X and Y won't be oppened  a on the same computer. Page X has one target users and Y has ather target users. What is your suggestion to solve this? Should i get something from database when somebody post on X and to manage this on page Y ?

Comment: maintain a server then, to communicate between changes on X and Y